# \Z doesn't match end of string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have this regex `(?P<url>http.{1,}?[\s)\Z])` to find a url ending in a `\s` character, close parenthesis, or end of string, but it only matches the first 2 cases.

How do I get it to match the third (end of string)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\Z` doesn't work inside a character sets - it just matches `Z` (most features are disabled inside a character class, including `.`, `+`, etc. Only other character classes work: `\w`, `\d`, etc).
You want to use an alternation: `(?:[\s)]|\Z)`.

In addition, `.{1,}?` is the same as `.+?`, so the whole pattern can be written as

```
(?P<url>http.+?(?:[\s)]|\Z))
```